# Is there an API with which I could obtain the exchange rate of bitcoin to dollar some time in the past by giving the desired time as parameter?

Tags: api, exchange-rate

I would also like the the result to be precise to hour (or minute).

It is for a java program.

I have looked around, but the service I have found could not satisfy my need:
http://www.coindesk.com/api/: only precise to date

https://api.coinbase.com/v1/prices/historical?page=1 (from https://community.coinbase.com/t/past-bitcoin-exchange-rates/1725): need to adjust page number to find the desired time (at which one wants the value of exchange rate)

http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/: I am not exactly sure what it does, but it seems that one needs to download different files from this site containing "USD" in the file names, check in all the files before finding the desired time

Answer (score 1):

The [CoinGecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api#explore-api) is what you are looking for. Here an example request:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=28-06-2021
```

You can pipe it through `jq`:

```
curl https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=28-06-2021 | jq .market_data.current_price.usd
```

Which gives you `39076.59377063225`. The exchange rate of bitcoin at the 28th of June 2021 in USD. It is not possible to get values for minutes/hours, just for days, as far as I am aware).

Answer (score 0):

You can use winkdex.com api, it accepts a unix timestamp as a parameter.
http://docs.winkdex.com/#price

Comment: It says that price is "The value of the WinkDex at the requested time in 0.01 USD". What is the value of WinkDex and what does it have anything to do with Bitcoin?

Comment: WinkDex is a bitcoin price index. It takes the information from several of the largest bitcoin exchanges and consolidates it into an average price.

Comment: The timestamp has an entry like: 2017-03-15T08:05:00Z. Am I correct that Z represent that the time is in UTC? What does the "T" in the middle mean?

Comment: @Aqqqq it's the ISO 8601 format. The T seems to act as a delimiter to separate the date and time. There's a whole wikipedia page dedicated to this time format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 . Z does indicated UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, the [CoinMarketCap API endpoint](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyQuotesHistorical) allows you to fetch a whole set of data points at once for a given time range.